# How to remove URLs in meta description tag

Tags: php, html, seo, vbulletin

I'm facing a small issue that Google and other search engines don't appreciate at all.

In my vbulletin forum, most of my threads start with a picture, then the text.

The problem is that when we look on search engines results, it looks like that :

[image: Example İmage]

So do you know if there is a way in php/html to remove urls from the meta tag ?

I know this is a problem with vbulletin engine but i've already asked them about sorting this issue and they said it was out of their charge.

By the way, the 2 php files responsible of the meta description tags include it (maybe it may help) :

In showthread.php :

```
$thread['meta_description'] = strip_bbcode(strip_quotes($thread['description']), false, true);
$thread['meta_description'] = htmlspecialchars_uni(fetch_censored_text(fetch_trimmed_title($thread['meta_description'], 500, false)));
```

And in get_forum.php :

```
if ($foruminfo['description'] != '') {
        $desc = prepare_utf8_string(strip_tags($foruminfo['description']));
        if (strlen($desc) > 0) {
            $out['desc'] = $desc;
        }
```

Thanks a lot for helping me, i know this is not the best place to ask for vbulletin help but even in their 2 official forums no one could help me properly to solve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Mention the meta tag in the header and crawl the website for google review. It may take time to crawl but it will work.

```
<meta name="description" content="This is an example of a meta description. This will often show up in search results.">
```

Comment: HI, thanks for the reply but there's already a description meta tag in the header for all my pages/threads..